# populate two variables in one query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am writing a stored procedure with a pivot in it. The pivot field names can change depending on the data in the table.

So I have the two variables below. However this seems quite inefficient because I run two queries on the same table, this is probably due to my lack of knowledge.

```
declare @code nvarchar(max) = ''
select @code = @code + '[' + Code + '],' from (select Code from myTbl) as c 
set @code = substring(@code , 1, len(@code ) - 1)

declare @Name nvarchar(max) = ''
select @Name = @Name + '[' + Name + '],' from (select Name from myTbl) as c
set @Name = substring(@Name , 1, len(@Name ) - 1)
```

Is it possible to populate both variables and only query the table once?

Comment: Can you query select c1 into v1, c2 into v2 from t?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can, here is a simple sample

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Code VARCHAR(45),
  Name VARCHAR(45)
);

INSERT INTO T VALUES
('Code1', 'Name1'),
('Code2', 'Name2');

DECLARE @Code VARCHAR(MAX) = '',
        @Name VARCHAR(MAX) = '';

SELECT @Code = @Code + QUOTENAME(Code) + ',',
       @Name = @Name + QUOTENAME(Name) + ','
FROM T;

SELECT @Code, @Name;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------------+------------------+
| No column name)  | (No column name) |
+------------------+------------------+
| [Code1],[Code2], | [Name1],[Name2], |
+------------------+------------------+
```

If you have SQL Server 2017, then no need to use substring, you can just use `STRING_AGG()` as

```
SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Code), ','),
       STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME(Name), ',')
FROM T;
```

**Returns:**

```
+------------------+------------------+
| (No column name) | (No column name) |
+------------------+------------------+
| [Code1],[Code2]  | [Name1],[Name2]  |
+------------------+------------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

I have stripped down the subquery (select Code from myTbl) as c since I do not think it added something in this context.

Given that. I believe it could work like this:

```
declare @code nvarchar(max) = ''
declare @Name nvarchar(max) = ''

select @code = @code + '[' + Code + '],', @Name = @Name + '[' + Name + '],' from myTbl 

set @code = substring(@code , 1, len(@code ) - 1)
set @Name = substring(@Name , 1, len(@Name ) - 1)
```